# Unbind then bind not working as I want it to

Tags: jquery, bind, unbind

I need to unbind a click event then after its fired I need to bind it again

Here's my script

```
$(function() {
    $('.bundle').unbind().click(function() {
        var codeList = "641351,641251,641253";
        $.fn.addBundle(codeList);
    });
    $('.bundle').bind().click(function() {
        var codeList = "641351,641251,641253";
        $.fn.addBundle(codeList);
    });
});
```

It's not working properly, can anyone let me know what I've don't wrong.

Thanks

Comment: what are you trying to do here

Comment: I have a page which loads into 2 templates 1 for desktop and 1 for mobile. Now if I use the code without the unbind it fires twice on mobile due to jquery mobile running the script twice, so I added the unbind which works on mobile but then causes the to only work once on desktop so I need to bind the click function to the button again after it's fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should unbind and bind the click event like this:

```
$(".bundle").unbind("click")
            .bind("click", function(){
                // do what you need onclick here
            });
```

As suggested in the [`bind() documentation`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), you should use `on()` and `off()` instead of `bind()` and `unbind()`:

```
$(".bundle").off("click")
            .on("click", function(){
                // do what you need onclick here
            });
```

See a working example [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/51dtzvuz/)